# Is there support for text-mode protobufs in haskell?

Tags: haskell, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol buffers for data serialization. hprotoc and Text.ProtocolBuffers gives excellent support for binary protobufs, but sometimes we need to use text representation. Is it already supported in haskell?

Comment: If it ain't on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/), it don't exist.

Comment: Is the [protocol-buffers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/protocol-buffers) package insufficient?  Note that I disagree with the "not on hackage / doesn't exist" phrase - while it is much less useful when code isn't on hackage, I've been using more and more non-hackage hosted Haskell over the past few years.  Yay [ninjas](https://github.com/glguy/Ninjas)!

Comment: As far as I was able to find, protocol-buffers can only read and write binary protobufs (messageGet/messagePut/...)

Comment: How about the [other protocol buffers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/protocol-buffers-descriptor) package?

Comment: Can't find any serialization functions in it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just patched hprotoc and protocol-buffers after all. How to push it to upstream? :)